# Best way do achieve this drop down navigation

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, dropdown

I have a drop down menu that I need to create in the footer of my page in mobile view, I have the layout done with the closed menu and arrows, but just wondering what the best method is to have it expanding. It's practically exactly the same as the menu shown in the image provided. Thanks!

[dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/489t7.png)

Comment: _"but just wondering what the best method is"_ - please don't ask question like this here. We are not here to do research work or experimentation on possible solutions for you. We can discuss problems with a specific approach you have chosen, but merely asking "show me the best way" means there is zero effort here from your end to try and solve the problem yourself first - and that is what is expected from you here. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Its upto your ease there are couple of frameworks which provide navigation bar by default just like bootstrap, material desing etc.

Comment: @Awais Yeah the framework I've been tasked with is very minimal and doesn't come with a menu unfortunately. I'd had a look around but didn't see any particular method that stood out. Was just curious as to whether someone else has achieved that result in a fairly simple manner without a framework.

Comment: Then You have 2 option Pure 'css' navigation on hover only and second 'javascript' with hover or on click .

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Some answers can be found on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp